# Changing the dataype of a Mat class instance in OpenCV C++ Interface

Tags: c++, image, opencv

How can I change the datatype used in storing the pixels in a `Mat` class instance?

For example, after reading an image using the line below:

```
Mat I = imread(file,0);
```

I obtain a grayscale image with pixels of type `unsigned char`. I want to change this to a `double`.

What's the best way to do the conversion? I wasn't able to find a function to do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is very simple. See the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) at OpenCV website.

Basically do

```
Mat double_I;
I.convertTo(double_I, CV_64F);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now i see why i didn't see that method. Because it is wrongly typed as copyTo in the methods list on the left part of the page.