# Set cv::Mat type without matrix size

Tags: opencv, matrix

I want to set the type of a `cv::Mat` object to `CV_32F`, but I don't care (at declaration time) of the matrix size.

There is any other way to do this:

`cv::Mat m (0,0,CV_32F);`

Something like:

```
cv::Mat m;
m.setType(CV_32F);
```

Comment: What about the number of channels?

Comment: I'm not expert about channels notion, I'll read about them and coming back to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the dataype of a Mat class instance in OpenCV C++ Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188352/changing-the-dataype-of-a-mat-class-instance-in-opencv-c-interface)

Comment: @rayryeng I've read that question, but I don't understand what `I` is. It seems we need two matrices here, I have and need only one in my case

Comment: You can simply do `cv::Mat1f m;` (a matrix of type CV_32FC1), or as suggested by rayryeng

Comment: `I` is the desired output image. You use an input image and convert it into whatever type you want.  You can then resize the image to whatever dimensions you want.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is use `cv::Mat1f` or e.g. `cv::Mat3f` (as @Miki suggested).

However, the place where it actually matters is at allocation time, so there's no problem just leaving `m` as is, and when you actually come to allocate it to the desired size, set it there (e.g. with `cv::Mat::create()`.

If `m` is just passed it auto allocating functions, then you don't actually need to set it at all.